# Does the inequality $\frac{1}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \ge \frac{c x^a}{{e^{|x|}}^b}$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, exponential-function

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$
It is possible to prove that
$$f(x)\ge \frac{c x^a}{{e^{|x|}}^b},$$
with $a, b, c\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$? Here the little-o-notation is meant as $x\to +\infty$.

If yes, how to do that? About me it should be true since there is the exponential below on the RHS, but I don't know how to formally prove that.

Could someone please help to understand that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The little $o$ notation requires that you specify where does $x$ tends to.

Comment: @PierreCarre thanks, edited.

Comment: The expression $\frac1x+o(\frac1x)$ does not define a function, but rather a property a function could have (or a family of functions). That being said, certainly $\frac1x+o(\frac1x) > \frac1{2x}$ when $x$ is sufficiently large, which should be enough to prove your desired inequality.

Comment: @C.Bishop How about using the *definition* of little-$o$?

Comment: @Gary, my definition of little-o is: $h\in o(1/x)$ if for every choice of a constant $k > 0$, you can find a constant $a$ such that the inequality $0\le h(x) < k \frac{1}{x}$ holds for all $x > a$. Could you please explain how to use here?

Comment: @Gary but also $h\in o(1/x) \iff \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{h(x)}{1/x}=0$.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you. Would you please give some more details about how to show that $\frac{1}{2x}$ satisfies the desired inequality? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $a, b, c > 0$. Then, you have that :

$$ \frac{c x^a}{e^{|x|^b}} = o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) $$

as $x \to \infty$ (by comparing the growth of $x^{a+1}$ and $e^{|x|^b}$). Therefore, you have :

$$ \frac{c x^a}{e^{|x|^b}} = o(f(x)) $$

This means that the inequality is true for $x$ large enough (depending on $a, b, c$). For a general $f$, you cannot prove that the inequality holds for every $x$, however.

EDIT : if

$$ \frac{c x^a}{e^{|x|^b}} = o\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) $$

then for $x$ large enough you have :

$$ \frac{c x^a}{e^{|x|^b}} \leq \frac{1}{2x} $$

On the other hand, since $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + o\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$, for $x$ large enough you also have :

$$ f(x) \geq \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2x} $$

Combining these two inequalities for $x$ large enough gives the answer.

Now, to prove that $x^a = o(e^{|x|^b})$ is the same as proving, for any $a > 0$, $x^a = o(e^x)$ (by considering $x^b$ instead of $x$, and $a' = a/b$). But this last equality is very well-known. One option to prove it is to write :

$$ e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} \geq \frac{x^n}{n!} $$

for positive $x$. By choosing $n$ large enough, $x^a = o(x^n)$ and thus $x^a = o(e^x)$.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please explain why $\frac{cx^a}{e^{|x|^b}} = o(f(x))$, too? Thank you.

Comment: And also why it means that the inequality is satisfied? Thank you

Comment: I edited. However, these computations are very classic, you should definitely learn how to do them properly.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, may I ask you why if both inequalities hold for $\frac{1}{2x}$ and not for example also for $\frac{1}{3x}$, $\frac{1}{4x}$ or something like that?

Comment: Well, you can choose $\frac{1}{3x}$ or more if you want, this is the point of $o()$. But here $1/2x$ is enough.

Comment: Sorry and finally may I ask you why $f(x)\ge \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x}$ with the "-" sign?

Comment: Well, I didn't prove this asymptotic (even though it is correct). I simply proved the inequality you asked for in my edit. I put a minus sign because I use that $o(1/x) \geq -1/2x$ for $x$ large enough.